# Page title with class based function in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I want to create page titles+subtitles which I wish to control and occasionally modify from the Admin space and pass them to the templates with class based model.

Yet, after I enter the inputs in the admin space, the variable I specify in the template provides not value. That is the fields are empty.

What do I do wrong? Any advise as to the logic I should use to pass the template?

models.py:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    page_subtitle = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.self
```

template:

```
<h3 class="title mb-0">{{page.page_title}}</h3>
<h6 class="title mb-0">{{page.page_title}}</h6>
```

Views:
I tried with different views, none of them functioned.

TemplateView:

```
class Page(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'painting_list.html'  # the template where I want to display the title

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page'] = self.Page
        return context
    
#I also tried it with:#
       context['page'] = Page.objects.get(id=1)
       return context
```

DetailView:

```
class Page(generic.DetailView):
     model = Page
     context_object_name = 'page'
     template_name = 'painting_list.html'
```

Comment: So `context['page'] = self.Page` isn't right, but `context['page'] = Page.objects.get(id=1)` should have worked providing you've created an object with the ID 1. If you hadn't it'd have errored.

Comment: @markwalker "If you hadn't it'd have errored" - The id=1 is right, verified in the admin. The spellings seem to be right as well... The other view based classes display the data... which means I have an error elsewhere... but where exactly?

Comment: you'll need to debug. Start by printing your context right before it's returned so you can verify what available to you in the template.